# Error importing adodbapi: "No such key..."

Tags: python, adodbapi

I would dearly love to use the adodbapi module, but I can't get it to import.  The latest version for Python 3.2 32 bits appears to have a syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "C:/Customers/Calvert/Scripts/test_adodb.py", line 1, in <module>
    import adodbapi
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .apibase import apilevel, threadsafety, paramstyle
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\apibase.py", line 495
    raise er,'No such key as "%s" in %s'%(repr(key),self.__repr__()),tr
```

What do I have to do to get around this?  Is this Python 2 syntax in a file designed for Python 3?  The name of the file I downloaded from SourceForge is pywin32-220.win32-py3.2.exe, and it was dated 1/11/16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was correct.  This module, labeled for python 3.2, contains Python 2 code.  I ran 2to3 on it, and the syntax error went away.

Comment: It is nice to see you where able to correct your problem !
Can you be a little more specific about "I ran 2to3 on it" ?
I tried calling '2to3 -w -W adodbapi.py' but I still have the same error message.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that was over three and a half years ago, and I don't remember exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the **adodbapi** codebase on both SourceForge (https://adodbapi.sourceforge.net/) and PyPy (https://pypi.org/project/adodbapi/2.4.2.1/) is either old and/or unmaintained.  It appears to live on through **pywin32**.

So upon encountering this error, in stead of the answer above, I simply installed pywin32 in place of adodbapi and my code worked fine:

```
pip uninstall adodbapi
pip install pywin32
```